# Don't display records with null values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, display

I have shapefile with 4000+ points and I would like to display only records that have values greater than zero in a specific column.

How do I stop ArcGIS from displaying all records including those that are null?

I've been trying to use the Display and Symbology options but can't seem to get rid of the points that are null, whatever I do they still show up, just without any color in them! I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.

Comment: Since it's not clear from either answer or your question if this is understood, I want to point out that zero is not the same thing as null. Zero is a value - null is nothing, literally. If you have true nulls *and* zeroes in your data, you need to filter them separately. For example `([Field Name] IS NOT 'NULL') AND ([Field Name] > 0)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use definition query to hide the `null` data. Have a look at this [help topic](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000002z000000).

So you will need to put something like:

```
[Field Name] IS NOT 'NULL'
```

This will effectively remove the null data from your map project without altering the dataset itself.

Comment: MAJ742 method is indeed better if you don't want to alter the data :)

Answer (score 3):

That sounds a bit odd. I think you should be able to set any value to null-color (double click symbol -> "no color").  Could you add a screenshot?

As a workaround you could make a separate file out of them:

1. Select by attributes (e.g."VALUE" IS NOT Null)
2. Export data
3. Display